# How to "Merge Selected Features" with python?

Tags: qgis, python, features, pyqgis, merge

I have been looking for the answer to this question for some time now, but can't seem to find it! My problem is straight forward: 
I have one layer
It contains lots of features (only polygons), say countrys
I want to merge some features together.
Using python.

I know that I can select features with the mouse and hit the "Merge selected features"-button, but that is to slow.
I can use python to select the features that i want, but how can i merge the selected features from python? (the features don't have a "common field" or something like that, what features are to be merged will be decided by in-data)

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [QgsGeometry.combine( QgsGeometry )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a63244d3435cc99794b82a6cbd0af0eb5) for that.

Just loop over all your features and call

```
geom = geom.combine( currentFeature.geometry() )
```

with geom being a QgsGeometry