# Merge selected feature pyqgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, merge, features

I want to merge the selected features. I found this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/59186/82192) but I can not do it. 
 
Can anybody help me?

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
obj1 = 24
obj2= 25
expr = QgsExpression( " \"ID_PARCEL\" = '{}' OR \"ID_PARCEL\"='{}' ".format(obj1,obj2))
it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
ids = [i.id() for i in it]
if ids == []:
    print 'ERROR - WAS NOT FOUND'
else:
    layer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
    selectFeatures = layer.selectedFeatures()

#MERGE SELECTED FEATURES
```

Comment: Your obj values are those related database fields type text or integer?  Right now your expression sees them as text because you have them surrounded with single quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this below

```
geom = None
for feat in selectFeatures:
    if geom == None:
       geom = feat.geometry()
    else:
       geom = geom.combine(feat.geometry())
```