# How to collect polygon features as one polygon in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, qgis-3

I want to collect polygon features from my layer to create one polygon features by considering the field attributes. I mean in attribute table if **"DN"** value of feature is **1000** that feature will be selected. After that all selected features should be treat as one polygon. I want to make it on the same layer without creating another layers etc. Is it possible by using pyqgis?

[image]

The selected features should be one polygon feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be of help but it was helpful for me during the same process but creating different feature.
[How to "Merge Selected Features" with python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59126/how-to-merge-selected-features-with-python)

Comment: combine command merge neighbour polygons. It does not look suitable for me